# 403 Forbidden error when downloading paid OpenMapTiles from website

Tags: openmaptiles

Every time there's a new release of OpenMapTiles tiles, I get a 403 forbidden error from maptiler.download.  If I wait a day or two, the download works, but I'm paying good money for these weekly updates, so how do I download them on time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like they fixed it by moving to a different CDN provider.